# Redirecionar pelo htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Boa tarde Galera, preciso fazer o seguinte no meu .htaccess.

Se o `REMOTE_ADDR` (IP) for nesse range 192.168.0.1 até 192.168.10.254 acessa por

> 192.168.0.5/sistema

Se o `REMOTE_ADDR` (IP) for um IP externo, tipo 177.45.85.95 acessa por

> sistema.empresa.com.br

vejam meu .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # Determina a base de reescrita
  RewriteBase /sistema
  # Verifica se a url nao corresponde a um arquivo existente
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  # Verifica se a url nao corresponde a um diretorio existente
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule .([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Com um **if directive** é possível fazer:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'www.example.com'">
Redirect / http://www.example.com/
</If>
```