# Como faço para redirecionar uma url inexistente pelo htaccess?

Tags: htaccess

Preciso redirecionar o seguinte link:

`http://dominio.com/receitas-user/ID_do_usuario/nome_do_usuario`

Para:

`http://dominio.com/receitas/author/nome_do_usuario`

Sendo `nome_do_usuario` e `ID_do_usuario` duas variáveis.

Tentei fazer da seguinte forma mas não funcionou:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/receitas-user/([0-9-a-z\-]+)/([0-9-a-z\-]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dominio.com/receitas/author/%2? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Não entendo muito de htaccess, mas posso palpitar que você está usando `%{QUERY_STRING}%` no lugar errado.

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131751/redirecionar-pelo-htaccess

Comment: Possível duplicata de [URL amigável, como fazer funcionar com HTACCESS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53973/url-amig%c3%a1vel-como-fazer-funcionar-com-htaccess)

Comment: Também não entendo muito amigo :\

Answer (score 0):

Parece que isso esta errado `%2`. O *match* deve ser com cifrão, assim `$2`

Deve ficar assim:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=""
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/receitas-user/([0-9-a-z\-]+)/([0-9-a-z\-]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://dominio.com/receitas/author/$2? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Não funcionou :(

Comment: @free4k poderia dar algum detalhe? Esta um pouco confuso de entender o que esta ocorrendo. De qualquer forma vou testar

Comment: Preciso redirecionar esse link http://mobiledev.ml/receitas-user/589/admin para http://mobiledev.ml/receitas/author/admin/ , sendo que o admin é o nome do usuário e vai ser diferente sempre. Simplesmente não funcionou pode acessar o link para poder ver melhor.

Comment: Ah entendi, o redirecionamento não esta acontecendo @free4k vou testar na minha máquina e volto assim que terminar.